# SharePoint 2019 crawl host named site collection failed

Tags: search-results, administration, 2019, backup, content-database

A couple of days ago, one of our clients moved a content database from production to development.

The migration went smoothly, but there's an issue: the search results within site collections are not showing up.

Previously, everything worked fine in both environments, but after restoring the content database in development, the search is not returning any results.

I've tried resetting the index and performing a full crawl, but the crawl log shows zero results in the success, warning, and error sections. I've checked almost everything, but I can't find any misconfigurations. Are there specific procedures for the restoration process or infrastructure configuration that I might be overlooking?

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-content-databases-2019

And: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1214084/sharepoint-2019-site-not-showing-results-after-suc

Here are things to check:

- The account used for the crawl needs to have the right permissions. It should be a member of the db_owner fixed database role for the content databases that you want to crawl.
- Make sure the Search Service Application is functioning correctly. If it’s not, you might need to delete and recreate it.
- Check the settings of your site. There’s an option called "Allow this site to appear in search results" - make sure it’s set to yes.
- Check query rule and result source settings which can affect search results. Make sure they’re configured correctly.
- If you’re moving from an older version of SharePoint, you need to do a database attach upgrade. This means you only upgrade the content for your environment, not the configuration settings.
- For each web application that existed in the old SharePoint environment, create a new one with the same URL (including name, port, and host header) and configure alternate-access mapping settings.

See the links above and let me know if it helps.